# What are reasons for not using Django Admin with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-admin, django-rest-framework

It's been a while since I last used Django for a project and there have been some really great advances in the core project and the ecosystem around it.

One of those is the mature API development libraries like django-rest-framework.

So far I'm loving it. But it seems that all the guides I've found are disabling the Django Admin when using Django Rest Framework.

The reasons I've seen given were essentially "We don't need it for anything" or "We aren't using sessions, which Admin uses, so it won't work, so we're not using it."

"Don't need it" is a valid reason.

**But other than that, are there reasons that it's bad practice to keep the Django Admin enabled when the project is primarily used as an API?**

For my purposes, I find it convenient to manage user permissions and as a simple way to code admin only functions for dealing with the underlying data.

*note: I've considered whether this question is designed to elicit opinions, which is not appropriate on SO. I believe that the answers I'm asking for will be technical or security based reasons with fact or experience based reasoning.*

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree.

On my current project, users are getting and setting **ALL** data via django-rest-framework.

Like you, I find the admin site convenient to manage user permissions, permissions groups, writing emails, sms, mobile applications push and more.

More, all these models are being translated, and translation is set in THE ADMIN SITE !!!

So, if we need a new object with translation, we do not need a new app release (example in pic of a question).

objects translations are readable and clear.

Data is organized nicely with minimal effort.

Admin get cool skins (jet / grappelli etc etc)

Language activation works like a charm in the APIViews.

[image]